# Cleaning up saved views Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a user who shares lots of saved views with her team. She has a huge list of My Views, and wants to clean it up, but does not want to delete the views, since the people she shared them with still use them.

When users want to remove a view that has been shared with them from the list, I instruct them to use Advanced Find > Saved Views > Share > select themselves > Remove Selected Items.

However, the creator of the view does not appear on this list.

We also don't want to delete or deactivate the view as it would do the same for all users.

Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

The creator is not appearing because it is the creator who has the rights on that view.

Ex: User A shares a view with User B, User B can't unassign User A just because it was created by A, and not himself.

If User A has a bunch of views shared with other team members, but User A doesn't want to see / use them, then better to create system views for that.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I would reassign the view to someone else, that will then remove it from her list.  To do this go to the same saved view window and Click Assign Saved View instead of share.

If the user ever needs to work on them again, they can be shared back to them to edit if need be.